# Getting object when key is unknown?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary

I have some json coming like the below, which i'm trying to turn into nsdictionaries. My problem is that the 1, 5 and 4 are keys, with unpredictable values. How would I get each object  - {"id":"A","name":"Nike"} - without knowing the key?

```
// JSON looks like:
{
"shops":
{
"1":{"id":"A","name":"Nike"},
"5":{"id":"G","name":"Apple"}
"4":{"id":"I","name":"Target"}
}
}

// how to step thru this?
NSArray *shopsArray = [[shopsString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"shops"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned object from `objectForKey:@"shops"` is actually an `NSDictionary` instance, not an `NSArray`, since the keys are actually strings, not numeric values.

For your purposes, you can simply call `-allValues` on the resulting `NSDictionary`.

```
NSDictionary *shops = [[shopsString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"shops"];

for(id obj in [shops allValues]) {
  //do stuff with obj...
}
```

**EDIT**: If you need ordering of the values, then you can do something like the following:

First, change the incoming JSON to this kind of structure:

```
{
  "shops":[
      {"key":"1", "id":"A","name":"Nike"},
      {"key":"5","id":"G","name":"Apple"},
      {"key":"4", "id":"I","name":"Target"}
  ]
}
```

Then, you can have ordering of the objects in the array.

```
NSArray *shops = [[shopsString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"shops"];
for(NSDictionary *shop in shops) {
  NSString *key = [shop objectForKey:@"key"];
  //...
}
```

Comment: Just checked json.org.  It is illegal to use a bare number as a **key** for a value in a JSON object.  Furthermore, if I were using a JSON parser that decoded a JSON object (as opposed to a JSON array) as an `NSArray` just because the keys all happened to be numbers, I'd throw it away and get one that worked.

Comment: @JeremyP Snap, I was thinking in pure JavaScript. Will revise.

Comment: Using NSDictionary and allValues returns a set which is not in the 1,5,4 order. Is there a way to step thru in order?